# Anaconda Navigator automatic close after open few seconds

Tags: anaconda

Windows 10 64bit system, successfully Install Anaconda3-4.2.0-Windows-x86_64, but when I open Anaconda Navigator, it only appears few seconds then close automatically. do anyone know what's the issue?

Answer (score 2):

1. Open Command prompt
2. `cd C:\Users\*username*\Anaconda3\Scripts`
3. `conda install "package name"

It will work like anaconda prompt

Answer (score 1):

Updating anaconda navigator should fix the issue. To update, paste below code in command prompt and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

```
conda update anaconda-navigator
```

Answer (score -1):

run below commands in anaconda command prompt and it should work.
$ conda update anaconda-navigator
$ conda update navigator-updater

it works for me.